# Chromium webcam usage auto-confirmation in kiosk mode

Tags: webcam, chromium

I am using Chromium in Kiosk mode, I'd like to know whether there is
any possibility to auto-confirm / auto-enable Chromium to use my webcam.
Currently it shows a confirmation message in case the webpage that is shown
is trying to access the webcam.
With Firefox it can be done with the media.navigator.permission.disabled flag.
Any idea for Chromium?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It appears --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream controls it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/839028)

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini: What are you talking about? (1) The author of this answer ***is*** the author of the question. (2) This looks like an answer to me.